# findbugs nonNull not finding all cases

Tags: java, exception, null, findbugs

I want to use FindBugs in my application in order to detect null pointer failures, my concern is for the code

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String nullStr = null;

        Person p = new Person();
        String mightBeNull = p.getAddress().getStreet();

        getString(mightBeNull);

        getString2(nullStr);
    }

    @NonNull
    static String getString(String street) {
        return street; 
    }

    @NonNull
    static String getString2(String nullString) {
        return nullString;    
        }
}
```

This code will surely result with null pointer exception as the Address structure inside person is not initiated, but FindBugs with `@NonNull` annotation will only detect the second case of `getString2(nullStr)`. If it does not support such cases can you refer me to some other tool that can detect such cases in compilation phase?

Comment: As for other tools, in case you are using Eclipse, you may want to have a look at http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_null_annotations.htm&cp=1_3_9_0 to get all the desired warnings right as you type incl. some quick fixes etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
static String getString(@NonNull String street) {
    return street; 
}
```

Because set `@NonNull` to the method's return-type means the result would never be `null`. If you set `@NonNull` to the method's argument you say: the Argument can not be `null`.

Comment: Amaizing how fast and preciesly this method works! :D